# Array initialization issue in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am having an issue with inputting information from one view controller into another. This function is in the second viewcontroller and is called multiple times in the first controller as it is in a for loop and there are multiple objects I want added to the array transfer_array. The objects are of type Poi and consist of a imageLocationX, imageLocationY, and name. The reason I have the BOOL was my attempt at only initializing the array once. The Poi object is added to the array the first time the function is called and the array is empty after the function is called again.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
- (id)display:(double)imageXX andY:(double)imageYY withName:(NSString *)namee ifDone:(BOOL *)donee{
    NSLog(@"````````````````````````````````````````````````````````");

    NSLog(donee ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    if(donee == NO){
        transfer_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    NSLog(@"imageX: %f",imageXX);
    NSLog(@"imageY: %f", imageYY);
    NSLog(@"name: %@", namee);

    labelPoi = [[Poi alloc] init];
    labelPoi.imageLocationX = imageXX;
    labelPoi.imageLocationY = imageYY;
    labelPoi.name = namee;
    [transfer_array addObject:labelPoi];


    NSLog(@"label.x: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationX, imageXX);
    NSLog(@"label.y: %f should be: %f", labelPoi.imageLocationY, imageYY);
    NSLog(@"label.name: %@ should be: %@",labelPoi.name,namee);
    NSLog(@"transssssfer: %lu", (unsigned long)transfer_array.count);

    return self;
}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Here is the log from the first time the function is called:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
2013-07-29 13:25:52.502 App[20856:11303] No
2013-07-29 13:25:52.502 App[20856:11303] imageX: 979.008057
2013-07-29 13:25:52.503 App[20856:11303] imageY: 115.728180
2013-07-29 13:25:52.503 App[20856:11303] name: Urgent Care
2013-07-29 13:25:52.503 App[20856:11303] label.x: 979.008057 should be: 979.008057
2013-07-29 13:25:52.503 App[20856:11303] label.y: 115.728180 should be: 115.728180
2013-07-29 13:25:52.503 App[20856:11303] label.name: Urgent Care should be:  Urgent Care
2013-07-29 13:25:52.503 App[20856:11303] transfer_array.count: 1
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

And the second time:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
2013-07-29 13:25:52.506 App[20856:11303] ````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
2013-07-29 13:25:52.506 App[20856:11303] Yes
2013-07-29 13:25:52.506 App[20856:11303] imageX: 224.485718
2013-07-29 13:25:52.506 App[20856:11303] imageY: 116.353401
2013-07-29 13:25:52.506 App[20856:11303] name: Student Health Center
2013-07-29 13:25:52.507 App[20856:11303] label.x: 224.485718 should be: 224.485718
2013-07-29 13:25:52.507 App[20856:11303] label.y: 116.353401 should be: 116.353401
2013-07-29 13:25:52.507 App[20856:11303] label.name: Student Health Center should be:  Student Health Center
2013-07-29 13:25:52.507 App[20856:11303] transfer_array.count: 0
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

I cannot access any of the information in the array because it is empty. Does anyone know how I can modify this so that the function will continually add the objects I want to add instead of remaining empty?

EDIT

This was how the function was called in the first view controller and this method was suggested to me by a friend

```
PictureViewController *newlabel = [[PictureViewController alloc] display:PointOfInterest.imageLocationX andY:PointOfInterest.imageLocationY withName:PointOfInterest.name ifDone:done];
            if(done == NO){
                done = YES;
            }
```

Comment: How is the `transfer_array` variable declared?

Comment: `@property (nonatomic,retain)NSArray *transfer_array;` in the .h file and `@synthesize transfer_array;` in the .m file for the second view controller

Comment: Create your own getter and do lazy instantiation (spelling?).

Comment: Put the array initialization in the init method.  Then no "first time through" flag is needed.  If you do use a "first time through" scheme, simply test the pointer for nil vs using a flag.  And assign to `self.transfer_array`, but do it with an autoreleased object:  `self.transfer_array = [NSMutableArray array];`.

Comment: Note that your property statement mis-declares transfer_array as NSArray.  The compiler SHOULD be screaming bloody murder about this, suggesting that you have another transfer_array defined somewhere as NSMutableArray.

Comment: (Show us the REAL code, with the other declaration.)

Comment: I added some code as an edit

Comment: Your claim is that there is no warning message on this statement:  `[transfer_array addObject:labelPoi];` ??

Comment: Then you have another declaration of transfer_array hiding somewhere.  Show it to us!

Comment: The only other one I found was in the .h `@interface PictureViewController : UIViewController{
    NSMutableArray *transfer_array;
}`

Comment: So you have two different properties in two different classes, both named "transfer_array".  Nothing wrong with that (in fact, it's done quite frequently), but you need to remember that having two variables/properties named the same does not make them the same -- they are quite distinct and "know" nothing about each other.

Answer (score 1):

Although esker's answer does remove the neccessity of the done and is thus preferable, that is not where your error was located. The problem that you were having was that each time you are going through your loop, you are initializing a new instance of PictureViewController. In this new object, the array has not yet been created and thus it is (null), returning a count of 0.

What you need to do is create one instance of the viewController and then add all of the objects to it. Also, in an init method, you want to call [super init] or another version of the super's initializer or another initializer you have that calls a super initializer.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! My last problem is still that when I try to access the array in another function, the value is returned as zero. Such as `- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"transfer_array count: %lu",(unsigned long)self.transfer_array.count);` returns 0

Comment: I think you want to add in your display method the following code `if ((self = [super init])) {//put all code here//} return self;` and put all of the code you currently have in the method inside of the if block.

Comment: I still get the count equal to 0 :/

Answer (score 1):

Sigh!!  Completely remove

```
NSLog(donee ? @"Yes" : @"No");
if(donee == NO){
    transfer_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Completely remove this, if you've added it:

```
// property getter for transfer_array: lazily load the object
- (NSArray *)transfer_array
{
    return (transfer_array ?: transfer_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Add this:

```
-(id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
       self.transfer_array = [NSMutableArray array];
   }
}

-(void)dealloc {
   self.transfer_array = nil;
   // If you are not using ARC include this line
   [super dealloc];
   // (If you're not sure, add it and then remove it if the compiler complains about it.)
}
```

Change all remaining occurrences of "transfer_array" to "self.transfer_array".

Comment: when I do this the count of the array inside the method is correct but the array is still empty outside of the method

Comment: "Outside of the method" -- Do you mean in another instance of your class??  Properties are tied to class instances, not the class.  This is a fundamental concept of objects you need to "internalize".

Comment: Yes, another instance of my class

Comment: So why do you expect values in one instance of your class to miraculously appear in another instance?

Comment: Is it possible to copy the array to use in another instance?

Comment: You can copy the array, or you can simply point at a single array from more than one object.  It depends on what you want to do.